# How to prove that the sequence $y_{n+1}=1-2y_n$ where $y_1=0$ has no convergent subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to prove that the sequence $y_{n+1}=1-2y_n$ where $y_1=0$ has no convergent subsequences?

I don't know where to even begin with this proof. I'm assuming I need to prove that $|y_n|$ converges to infinity first.

Comment: Hint:1) think of the comparison test from calculus 2) write out some values of the sequence to see if a pattern emerges, set $y_0 = c, c \in \mathbb{R}$. Additionally, I recommend including what you have tried otherwise your questions will likely be downvoted and closed.

Comment: OK, so begin by proving $|y_n|$ converges to infinity.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: You can show that $y_n  = \frac{{( - 1)^n 2^{n - 1}  + 1}}{3}$.

Comment: You can argue that such a subsequence will either eventually be strictly positive or strictly negative. Now since the signs alternate we can examine $y_{n+2}=1-2y_{n+1}=1-2(1-2y_n)=4y_n-1$ to figure out why such subsequences can't exist.

Answer (score 0):

We have: $|y_{n+1}| = |2y_n - 1| \ge 2|y_n| - 1\ge 2(2|y_{n-1}| - 1)-1=4|y_{n-1}|-3\ge 4(2|y_{n-2}|-1)-3=8|y_{n-2}|-7\ge 8(2|y_{n-3}|-1)-7=16|y_{n-3}|-15 \ge 2^{n-3}|y_4|-(2^{n-3}-1)=3\cdot 2^{n-3}-2^{n-3}+1=2^{n-2}+1, \forall n\ge 4$. Thus $|y_{n}| \to +\infty$. You can fill the rest of the work.

Answer (score 0):

The first few values are
$0, 1, -1, 3, -5,
11, -21
$.
So it looks like it is
growing exponentially
with alternating signs.

Any sequence with
$|y_{n+1}|
\gt |y_n|+a
$
for some $a > 0$
and all large enough $n$
can not have a convergent subsequence.
If it does
and the subsequence is
$(y_{n_k})$,
then,
for any $c > 0$
$|y_{n_{k+1}}-y_{n_k}|
\lt c
$
for all large enough $k$.

Since
$|y_{n+1}|
\gt |y_n|+a
$,
$|y_{n+k}|
\gt |y_n|+ka
$
so,
if $n > m$,
$|y_{n}-y_m|
\gt (n-m)a
$.
Therefore
$|y_{n_{k+1}}-y_{n_k}|
\gt a(n_{k+1}-n_k)
\ge a$.
This implies that
$c > a$
which is false
as we can chose $0 < c < a$.

In our case,
if $|y_n| > 2$
then
$|y_{n+1}|
=|1-2y_n|
\ge 2|y_n|-1
$
so
$|y_{n+1}|-|y_n|
\ge |y_n|-1
\gt 1$
and
$|y_{n+1}|
\gt 2$.

Therefore
$y_n$
does not have a
convergent subsequence.

We can also find
an explicit form.
In this case,
based on experience,
I would try to find a $c$
such that
$y_{n+1}+c
=-2(y_n+c)
$.
From this,
an explicit form is
readily found.

Regrouping this,
$y_{n+1}
=-3c-2y_n
$,
so $-3c=1$
or
$c=-\frac13$.

As a check,
if
$y_{n+1}-\frac13
=-2(y_n-\frac13)$,
then
$y_{n+1}
=1-2y_n
$.

By induction,
$y_{n}-\frac13
=(-2)^k(y_{n-k}-\frac13)$.
Setting $k=n-1$,
$y_{n}-\frac13
=(-2)^{n-1}(y_{1}-\frac13)
=-\frac13(-2)^{n-1}
$
so
$y_{n}
=\frac13(1-(-2)^{n-1})
$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear recurrence for which you can have an expression for the general term. You can start by solving the homogeneous equation, $y_{n+1} = -2 y_n$, yielding $y_n^h = c (-2)^n$ and then find a particular constant solution. This way you conclude that $y_n = c (-2)^n + \frac 13$. Finally, using the initial condition, $y_n = \frac 16 (-2)^n + \frac 13$. Given the general term for this sequence, the conclusion follows trivially.

Answer (score -1):

$y_{n+1}=1-2y_n, y_1=0$. $0,1,-1,3,-5,11,-21,43:1,-2,4,-8,16,-32,64$

$y_n=\frac{(-2)^{n-1}-1}{-3}$. Take consecutive differences and one finds the original sequence is a the geometric series starting with 1 and having common ratio -2. This tells us all the elements of the sequence are distinct integers. The smallest possible difference between two distinct integers is 1. One can use this to prove there are no convergent subsequences.

Suppose some subsequence of the set converges to real  $a$. Then by definition, $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \ y_n \ s.t. |y_n-a|<\epsilon$

$a-\epsilon<y_n<a+\epsilon$. We must have some $y_m \ s.t. y_n<y_m<a+\epsilon $ else we can select $\epsilon=(a-y_n)/2$ and disprove convergence. On the other hand. $|y_n-a|<|y_m-a|<\epsilon$

$|y_m-y_n|=|y_m-a + a-y_n|\le |y_m-a|+|y_n-a|<2\epsilon$. We can choose any $\epsilon$ because of convergence. Pick $\epsilon=1/4$ and we have $|y_m-y_n|<1/2$, two integers whose difference is less than 1. Another contradiction.

Comment: The general term you propose for $y_n$ does not work.

Comment: @PierreCarre, was the re indexing the only problem you saw?